# Update Image from Spinner selection

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, updates

I'm stuck at this point:

I have a RecyclerView with a list of CardViews.

When a button is pressed, the addItem(); method is called, which obviously adds an item.

Here's how:

```
String text = hwtext.getText().toString();
    mList.add(new HomeWork_Item(the.image.I.want, text));
    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mList.size());
```

Which works, great!

Now, I have added a Spinner. The spinner contains a few Subjects. If, let's say, the subject history is selected, I'd like to change `the.image.I.want` from the `addItem();` method to another one in the drawable.

I tried using glide but this didn't work:

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    String SpinnerText = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), SpinnerText, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (SpinnerText.equals("History")) {

 Glide.with(getActivity()).load(R.drawable.history).into(R.id.theImageView);

    }

}
```

Notice: The Item would be added only when a button is pressed which calls the method to add it. After selecting a Subject it should just prepare the Image to use when the Item will be added.

Thanks!

Crash Logcat:

```
2019-03-08 14:59:10.328 9808-9808/com.reogen.ssr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.reogen.ssr, PID: 9808
java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null
    at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:31)
    at com.bumptech.glide.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:25)
    at com.bumptech.glide.RequestBuilder.into(RequestBuilder.java:685)
    at com.reogen.ssr.Fragments.Homework.onItemSelected(Homework.java:170)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:1331)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:1320)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:1282)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Comment: Can you call notifyDataSetChanged() after you do the glide stuff?

Comment: Dosen't  look like I can

Comment: What do you mean with you can't

Comment: Inside the if statement, after my "Glide Stuff", notifyDataSetChanged() doesn't exist, it's not valid

Comment: You can't call mAdapter.notifydatasetchanged()?

Comment: Oh I have to use the adapter... you're right, sorry for that

Comment: It crashes tho, the Glide stuff comes out as null

Comment: change getActivity() for view.getContext()

Comment: Crashes. "Argument musrt not be null", pointing to the Glide Line

Comment: I casted the Image as `ImageView image = R.id.image`, and put in glide `into.(image)`. If I type directly `into(R.id.image)` I get an error... But why not with the variable? It says it cannot put it into an int

Comment: You need to specify which ImageView you want, for sure, not with the Id with the object itself, like if you are on viewHolder.imageView, you can do ImageView image = findViewById(R.id.image); and then in glide just pass image and it would work

Answer (score 0):

Create an `ImageView` as

```
ImageView historyImage = findViewById(R.id.historyImage);
```

Then in your glide you do this :

```
Glide.with(view.getContext()).load(R.drawable.history).into(historyImage);
```

You are passing an int into the `into` and you should pass the `ImageView` directly.

### Edit

Change your code to this one

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_homework, container, false);
insert = rootView.findViewById(R.id.insert_text);
    hwtext = rootView.findViewById(R.id.hwinput);
SubjectImage = rootView.findViewById(id.HWImage);

   spinner = rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner);
   buildView(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }


    public void buildView(View rootView) {
    mRecyclerView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.RecycleHW);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    mAdapter = new HomeWorkAdapter(mList);

    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mManager);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
}
```

Comment: Again, `java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument must not be null`

Comment: What's null? which argument

Comment: I have no Idea, it just says that. I suppose the imageView is, since there isn't one until the item is created through a button click

Comment: post logcat with the nullpointer please, try to put view.getContext().findViewById...

Comment: Added the logcat, now I'll try your suggestion

Comment: Nope, cannot use .into(view.getContext.findViewById)

Comment: .into(yourimage) and before call this you add ImageView yourimage = view.getContext()findViewById(R.id.yourid);

Comment: Same exact logcat. Argument must not be null... Why is this so difficult??

Comment: Yes, https://gist.github.com/ShadeReogen/cad32e733c1dbd984bdeb47dac4926bf

Comment: I understand the edits you made, but now it crashes when I try to open up the fragment 'cause `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference`.. It points out to the line mList.getSize() in the Adapter for the items

Comment: what's the status of the answer @ShadeReogen

Comment: Still null, I've moved on, I'll get to it later since now I still cannot resolve that